# Comparing directories in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

I have two directories that I want to compare and I want to find the following using Python (while ignoring the structure of each directory):

- files with the same name, but different content
- files with the same content, but different name
- files with both unique content and name, that exist only in one directory but not the other

Is there a robust Python library to do this? I looked everywhere, but I can't find anything that can do all of the above. If possible, I wouldn't want to create one from a scratch since it is potentially a very [complex](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cautions.html) endeavour.

All I can do so far is make a list of files, but I'm utterly lost how to proceed from there.

```py
from pathlib import Path

file_list = []
file_path = Path.cwd()
for file in file_path.rglob('*'): 
    if file.is_file():
        file_list.append(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

## This method prints result of comparison between directories.

```
result  =  filecmp.dircmp('dir1', 'dir2')
result.report()
diff dir1 dir2
Only in dir1 : ['newfile.txt']
Identical files : ['file1.txt']
Differing files : ['file2.txt']
"""
```

Comment: I've checked filecmp out, but from what I can tell, it can't find files with the same content but different name. Also, the 'Only in' method seems to work based on filenames, not contents. Which means that it can't actually find truly unique files. The documentation is oddly very sparse too for some reason.